# How to get value from tkinter Combobox binded func

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I'm a rookie in Python. I want to get a dynamic value from ComboboxSelected to self.wwc, but it doesn't work. Could you give some advises or suggestions to me? Thanks.

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
    
     def __init__(self, master):
         tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
         self.grid()
         self.createWidgets()
     
     def createWidgets(self):

        # Company Options
        df3 = pd.read_sql(wwc_query, conn)
        wwc_set = df3.loc[:,'Company']
        self.comboboxText = tk.StringVar()
        self.wwc_list = wwc_set.to_string(index=False)
        self.companyOpt = ttk.Combobox(self.wrapper1, textvariable=self.comboboxText, state='readonly')
        self.companyOpt['values']=self.wwc_list
        self.companyOpt.set('-Select-')
        self.companyOpt.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.N)
        self.companyOpt.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.company_selected)

        # Department List
        query_ww= """select distinct Department 
                    from MTK_MyAssetsTrack.dbo.v_MTK_OA_Client_Nologon_By_Days_Except_IT
                    where Company = ?
                    order by Department asc"""
        
        self.wwc = ' '
        df = pd.read_sql(query_ww, conn, params={self.wwc})
        self.d_set = df.loc[:,'Department']
        self.department =tk.Listbox(self.wrapper1, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE, yscrollcommand=self.yScroll.set, width=40)
        self.department.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.department.insert(tk.END, *self.d_set)
        self.yScroll['command'] =self.department.yview

    def company_selected(self, event):

        if self.companyOpt.get():
            self.wwc = self.companyOpt.get()
        return self.wwc
```

Comment: When asking questions here is best to provide a [mre] (MRE). That means getting rid of everything not related to the problem, like pandas and reading dataframe, in this case.

Comment: What do you mean *"it doesn't work"*?  Did you try to print out the value of `self.wwc` inside `company_selected()` and see whether it is the value you expect?

Comment: Your current code is also incomplete, there are references to an undefined `self.wrapper1`.

Comment: Note that changing value of `self.wwc` inside `company_selected()` will not update the content of `self.department` *dynamically*.  You need to put the code on populating data into `self.department` inside `company_selected()`.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for not giving sufficient information, and I've solved this problem by myself.
Here is my code below.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from pandas import DataFrame
import win32com.client as client

class Application(tk.Frame):
    

    
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()
        
        
    def createWidgets(self):
        
        self.wrapper1 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Search")
        self.wrapper1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.wrapper2 = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Result")
        self.wrapper2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.W)
        
        
        # Company Options
        df3 = pd.read_sql(wwc_query, conn)
        wwc_set = df3.loc[:,'Company']
        self.comboboxText = tk.StringVar()
        self.wwc_list = wwc_set.to_string(index=False)
        self.companyOpt = ttk.Combobox(self.wrapper1, textvariable=self.comboboxText, state='readonly')
        self.companyOpt['values']=self.wwc_list
        self.companyOpt.set('-Select-')
        self.companyOpt.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.N)
        self.companyOpt.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.company_selected)
        

        # search
        self.search_var =tk.StringVar()
        self.search_var.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode: self.update_list())
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.wrapper1, textvariable=self.search_var, width=30)
        self.entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.N )
        self.yScroll = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        
        
        # Department List
        query_ww= """select distinct Department 
                    from MTK_MyAssetsTrack.dbo.v_MTK_OA_Client_Nologon_By_Days_Except_IT
                    where Company = ?
                    order by Department asc"""
        
        self.wwc = ' '
        df = pd.read_sql(query_ww, conn, params={self.wwc})
        self.d_set = df.loc[:,'Department']
        self.department =tk.Listbox(self.wrapper1, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE, yscrollcommand=self.yScroll.set, width=40)
        self.department.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.N+tk.E+tk.W)
        self.department.insert(tk.END, *self.d_set)
        self.yScroll['command'] =self.department.yview

    def company_selected(self, event):
        
        query_wwc = """select distinct Department 
                    from MTK_MyAssetsTrack.dbo.v_MTK_OA_Client_Nologon_By_Days_Except_IT
                    where Company = ?
                    order by Department asc"""
        
        if self.companyOpt.get():
            self.wwc = self.companyOpt.get()
        self.df_wwc = pd.read_sql(query_wwc, conn, params={self.wwc})
        self.wwcd_set = self.df_wwc.loc[:,'Department']
        self.d_set = self.wwcd_set
        self.department.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.department.insert(tk.END, *self.d_set)
```

Comment: You should add explanation of what you have done in order to solve the problem, otherwise the answer has low value to future readers